# React Native get text of clicked text field

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

i want to get the get the text of the clicked text field.

```
<Text style={styles.name}>
    {item.author}
    <Text style={styles.date}> {item.date}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.category}> · {item.type}</Text>
</Text>
```

i want to return the text of the textfield, where `{item.author}` is the first child

Comment: `<Text>` has an `onPress` attribute. Check what the `event` contains, it might have info on text contained but most likely note. So maybe you will have to just `onPress` to each `<Text>` so like `<Text style={styles.date} onPress={()=>alert(item.date)}> {item.date}</Text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean when you say you want to return the text...but you can get the item which contains all text values:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.doSomething(item)}>
  <Text style={styles.name}>
    {item.author}
    <Text style={styles.date}> {item.date}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.category}> · {item.type}</Text>
  </Text>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```